# How can I get the second field, based on the first field, shown in a ListBox

Tags: vb.net

I have a ListBox that is reading data from a SQL Server table.  The table has only two fields; the 1st is the report name and the 2nd is the SQL that I want to execute and display in a GridView.  My code looks like this.

```
    myItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem
    SqlStr = "select ReportSQL from [All_Report_Names] Where ReportName = '" & myItem & "'"

    SqlStr = Replace(SqlStr, startDate, VBstartDate)
    SqlStr = Replace(SqlStr, endDate, VBendDate)
```

It almost seems like it would be: `myItem = ListBox1.SelectedItem.Offset(0,1)`

Of course that doesn't work.

The ListBox points to this SQL Server table.

[image]

The first field is shown in the ListBox.  When I click on it, I want to read in the seconf column, which has all my SQL scripts.  Finally, I do a REPLACE() on the startDate and endDate, and pass those from my Form into the SQL.

The ListBox reads from the SQL Server table below.

Comment: You have to use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.

Comment: Yes, I'm handling all of that in SQL.

Comment: If the ListBox has DataRows, you would have to cast the SelectedItem: `myItem = DirectCast(ListBox1.SelectedItem, DataRow)(1).ToString`

Comment: Thanks, but now I'm getting this: System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.Data.DataRow'.'

Comment: Then the ListBox only has strings, not a table.  What's in the ListBox?  What is myItem giving you?

Comment: Yes, it has only strings.  I just updated my original post.

Comment: Call me confused.  Is your question regarding how to call your query?

Comment: I think we are saying the same thing.  So, yes.

Comment: What you should be doing is populating a `DataTable` with all the data you need and binding it to the `ListBox`.  You can set the `DisplayMember` to "ReportName" and the `ValueMember` to "ReportSQL".  The user will then select a report name from the list and you can get the corresponding SQL from the `SelectedValue` property.

Comment: Yeah, I think that's exactly what I'm looking for.  I did some research on it and tried a few things, but couldn't get anything to work.  Could you post some sample code to show me what it would look like, given the scenario I described?  Thanks.

Comment: a) there is no `startDate` or `endDate` in the `SqlStr` shown so that is confusing to us b) `Replace` is not the same as Parameters c) If you want the user to see one thing (ReportName) but your code to have access to something else (ReportSQL) use a DataSource and DisplayMember and ValueMember